# Variable var_4 filled with value -1

Tags: ida, disassembly, c++

Who can explain to me, why this line code there is before each `jmp` or end of some part of code where there is label. What this line of code is to do?

```
mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
```

This is `WinMain` used C++. I used try/catch.

```
.text:00411260                 push    ebp
.text:00411261                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00411263                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00411265                 push    offset unk_414FC8
.text:0041126A                 push    offset loc_411050
.text:0041126F                 mov     eax, large fs:0
.text:00411275                 push    eax
.text:00411276                 mov     large fs:0, esp
.text:0041127D                 add     esp, 0FFFFFFA0h
.text:00411280                 push    ebx
.text:00411281                 push    esi             ; uType
.text:00411282                 push    edi             ; uType
.text:00411283                 mov     [ebp+var_18], esp
.text:00411286                 mov     [ebp+var_1C], 64h
.text:0041128D                 mov     [ebp+var_20], 96h
.text:00411294                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0
.text:0041129B                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_1C]
.text:0041129E                 add     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:004112A1                 mov     [ebp+var_24], eax
.text:004112A4                 int     3               ; Trap to Debugger
.text:004112A5                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:004112AC                 jmp     short loc_4112D2
.text:004112AE ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:004112AE                 mov     eax, 1
.text:004112B3                 retn
.text:004112B4 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:004112B4                 mov     esp, [ebp-18h]
.text:004112B7                 push    0
.text:004112B9                 push    offset Caption  ; "Error1"
.text:004112BE                 push    offset Caption  ; "Error1"
.text:004112C3                 push    0               ; hWnd
.text:004112C5                 call    ds:__imp__MessageBoxA@16 ; MessageBoxA(x,x,x,x)
.text:004112CB                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:004112D2
.text:004112D2 loc_4112D2:                             ; CODE XREF: WinMain+4Cj
.text:004112D2                 mov     [ebp+var_28], 64h
.text:004112D9                 mov     [ebp+var_2C], 96h
.text:004112E0                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 1
.text:004112E7                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_28]
.text:004112EA                 add     eax, [ebp+var_2C]
.text:004112ED                 mov     [ebp+var_30], eax
.text:004112F0                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_30]
.text:004112F3                 cdq
.text:004112F4                 xor     ecx, ecx
.text:004112F6                 idiv    ecx
.text:004112F8                 mov     [ebp+var_30], eax
.text:004112FB                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00411302                 jmp     short loc_411328
.text:00411304 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00411304                 mov     eax, 1
.text:00411309                 retn
.text:0041130A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0041130A                 mov     esp, [ebp-18h]
.text:0041130D                 push    0
.text:0041130F                 push    offset Text     ; "Error2"
.text:00411314                 push    offset Text     ; "Error2"
.text:00411319                 push    0               ; hWnd
.text:0041131B                 call    ds:__imp__MessageBoxA@16 ; MessageBoxA(x,x,x,x)
.text:00411321                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00411328
.text:00411328 loc_411328:                             ; CODE XREF: WinMain+A2j
.text:00411328                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0041132A                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_10]
.text:0041132D                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
.text:00411334                 pop     edi
.text:00411335                 pop     esi
.text:00411336                 pop     ebx
.text:00411337                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:00411339                 pop     ebp
.text:0041133A                 retn    10h
.text:0041133A WinMain         endp
```

Answer (score 4):

In binaries compiled with Visual C++, functions which use SEH (Structured exceptions handling), usually use `var_4` (`[ebp-4]`) for the *try level* value (value specifying the current SEH scope block).

The value 0FFFFFFFFh (or -1) is used for the outermost, global function scope (i.e. before and after any `__try` blocks).

For more info check [my OpenRCE article](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21).

Comment: I know a bit about SEH and EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION structures.  Yes, I used C++ __try for this code. Looked at your article, very interesting, so, usage var_4 variable is to marks position of __try blocks in program binary code?

Comment: Additionally I am interesting, what is this line of code doing:
`text:00411265 push offset unk_414FC8`
this line of code has stub FFFFFFFF and points to exit:
`text:004112AE                 mov     eax, 1
.text:004112B3                 retn`
This line of code is part of SEH, too? Or what?

Comment: The first lines set up the SEH handler for the function and the other snippet is the `__except()` filter code.

Comment: I thought SEH handler is `.text:0041126A                 push    offset loc_411050`. what difference between `.text:00411265                 push    offset unk_414FC8` and `.text:0041126A                 push    offset loc_411050`? It are both SEH handlers? But this function is not present in SEH chain `.text:00411265                 push    offset unk_414FC8`. SEH chain started in `.text:0041126A                 push    offset loc_411050` and not contains unk_414FC8. I am a bit confused, explain please.

Comment: Check Appendix I in the article

Comment: Ana María I just wanted add thank more again for suggested edit I am fan of pirates of carribean, too